# How can I configure SQL Server 2012 to use multiple NICs?

Tags: load-balancing, sql-server-2012

How can I configure SQL Server 2012 to use multiple NICs?

I've a server with 4 NICs. I want to use 2 NICs to query my databases, and 2 NICs to retrieve results from them.

I want them to work in load balancing mode and still continue to work if one nick is down.

It is possible?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve by separating the NICs for different purposes?

Answer (score 6):

As long as the OS is configured for NIC teaming SQL server will use the team.  SQL Server doesn't talk directly to the network cards, all the communications goes through the TCP/IP stack which is a part of the OS.  However the OS is configured to use the NICs will be how SQL Server uses the NICs.

To do what you describe will require doing NIC bonding (aka. NIC teaming).

Comment: ok, i've found out nic teaming in windows server 2012, but what about separing query from result?

Comment: You aren't going to be able to force the request down one NIC and the results down a different NIC.  All you can do is let Windows load balance the traffic across the all the NICs which are teamed (or bonded) together.  Windows will pipe a single large result across multiple NICs at the same time as it sees fit.